# Android GridView Focus Issueon children?

Tags: android, gridview, focus, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a GridView to which a custom adapter is set. getView() method of the custom adapter returns a LinearLayout with two TextView and an EditText arranged horizontally. I have made a custom numeric keyboard for entering text in the EditText. Keyboard contains NEXT and PREV buttons as well which are creating problems. I want NEXT button to automatically focus the next EditText in the next row and similarly PREV button. NEXT button onKeyPress seems like:

```
View v=getWindow().getCurrentFocus().focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
if(v!=null)
v.requestFocus();
```

The code seems right. The problem is, suppose currently only three rows are visible of gridView,if the focus is on the third EditText and NEXT is pressed,it then focuses on nothing. I dont know how to solve this issue. If anyone knows how to solve it.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you maintain a collection of ids of all the `editText`'s in the same order, while adding them for rendering.

In that case, for `clickHandler` or NEXT/PREV button, u can check following:

1. `clickHandler` of PREV: if present selection is first in list, then you might want to set focus on last element in list.
2. `clickHandler` of NEXT: if present selection is last in list, then you might want to set focus on first element in list.

Alternatively, if you do not want a list roll back functionality, you can just check the position of element in list, and handle the brink elements any way u want them to be.

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

HTH

Comment: Yes I can save a collection of ids of EditTexts but how to inform the handler which is the next EditText and which is the previous one? I mean the syntax. If you can help me with that too..

Thanx

Comment: I mean can you tell me waht to write in the code, I am new to android?